# Does puting a block on a sync GCD queue locks that block and pauses the others?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, queue, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

I read that GCD synchronous queues (dispatch_sync) should be used to implement critical sections of code. An example would be a block that subtracts transaction amount from account balance. The interesting part of sync calls is a question, how does that affect the work of other blocks on multiple threads?

Lets imagine the situation where there are 3 threads that use and execute both system and user defined blocks from main and custom queues in asynchronous mode. Those block are all executed in parallel in some order. Now, if a block is put on a custom queue with sync mode, does that mean that all other blocks (including on other threads) are suspended until the successful execution of the block? Or does that mean that only some lock will be put on that block while other will still execute. However, if other blocks use the same data as the sync block then it's inevitable that other blocks will wait until that lock will be released.

IMHO it doesn't matter, is it one or multiple cores, sync mode should freeze the whole app work. However, these are just my thoughts so please comment on that and share your insights :)

Comment: There are no "synchronous queues". There is synchronous dispatch (which waits for the block to finish) and asynchronous dispatch (which just adds the block to the queue). And there are concurrent and sequential queues. Sequential queues can't be used to _implement_ critical sections, but they are very useful to avoid _the need_ for critical sections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Synchronous dispatch suspends the execution of your code until the dispatched block has finished. Asynchronous dispatch returns immediately, the block is executed asynchronously with regard to the calling code:

```
dispatch_sync(somewhere, ^{ something });
// Reached later, when the block is finished.

dispatch_async(somewhere, ^{ something });
// Reached immediately. The block might be waiting
// to be executed, executing or already finished.
```

And there are two kinds of dispatch queues, serial and concurrent. The serial ones dispatch the blocks strictly one by one in the order they are being added. When one finishes, another one starts. There is only one thread needed for this kind of execution. The concurrent queues dispatch the blocks concurrently, in parallel. There are more threads being used there.

You can mix and match sync/async dispatch and serial/concurrent queues as you see fit. If you want to use GCD to guard access to a critical section, use a single serial queue and dispatch all operations on the shared data on this queue (synchronously or asynchronously, does not matter). That way there will always be just one block operating with the shared data:

```
- (void) addFoo: (id) foo {
    dispatch_sync(guardingQueue, ^{ [sharedFooArray addObject:foo]; });
}

- (void) removeFoo: (id) foo {
    dispatch_sync(guardingQueue, ^{ [sharedFooArray removeObject:foo]; });
}
```

Now if `guardingQueue` is a serial queue, the add/remove operations can never clash even if the `addFoo:` and `removeFoo:` methods are called concurrently from different threads.

Comment: Then what about the situation where two blocks (one asyn A and the other sync B) are executed on different threads but both uses the same object, for example account with a balance. If sync B block starts in the middle timeline and updates the balance while block A tries to read an account then will there be a race? Do we have explicitly do something to prevent the block A from reading the data?

Comment: As far as I understand from your question, using a serial queue and dispatching a block with sync mode just freezes the caller code until the block is finished. No other protections for locking shared resources from read/write are made.

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about sync/async blocks or queues. Synchronous or asynchronous is just the way you dispatch a block on a queue. I have updated the answer to explain how to guard a critical section with GCD, hope that helps.

Comment: +1 AIUI this is the correct way to synchronise a critical object. If you only make changes to it from one queue and that is a serial queue then there will never be a clash because only one block can be working on it at the same time

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't.

The synchronised part is that the block is put on a queue but control does not pass back to the calling function until the block returns.

Many uses of GCD are asynchronous; you put a block on a queue and rather than waiting for the block to complete it's work control is passed back to the calling function.

This has no effect on other queues.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to serialize the access to a certain resource then there are at least two
mechanisms that are accessible to you. If you have an account object (that is unique
for a given account number), then you can do something like:

```
@synchronize(accountObject) { ... }
```

If you don't have an object but are using a C structure for which there is only one
such structure for a given account number then you can do the following:

```
// Should be added to the account structure. 
// 1 => at most 1 object can access accountLock at a time.
dispatch_semaphore_t accountLock = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);

// In your block you do the following:
block = ^(void) {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(accountLock,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    // Do something
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(accountLock);
};

// -- Edited: semaphore was leaking.
// At the appropriate time release the lock
// If the semaphore was created in the init then 
// the semaphore should be released in the release method.
dispatch_release(accountLock);
```

With this, regardless of the level of concurrency of your queues, you are guaranteed that only one thread will access an account at any given time.

There are many more types of synchronization objects but these two are easy to use and
quite flexible.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Minor typeo though. `dispatch_semaphore_wait` takes 2 arguments. Something like `dispatch_semaphore_wait(accountLock, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` should do the trick.

Comment: The documentation says you're supposed to `dispatch_release` when you're done with your semaphore. I crash every time I do though. Not sure what I'm doing though. Either way, the semaphore in this snippet is leaking.

Comment: You are correct the semaphore is leaking. You might be crashing because you are trying to release the semaphore at the wrong moment? Assuming that the lock is created with the object it should be released when the object is released. I'll add a comment in the code above to that effect.